# $T(n,k)$ is the number of k-element subsets of $\left\{1, 2, \cdots, n\right \}$ having pairwise coprime elements.

Tags: number-theory

Based on https://oeis.org/A186974 
This is based on the irregular triangle.
However the formula of the sum $S(n,k)$ is not given(A186972), how to generate this for any $n$ and $k$

$$T(n,k)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} S(i,k)$$

I am trying to estimate the number of $k$-elements sets $\leq n$ that are co-primes.
Also to find these sets, is there any approach other than brute force. This seems like an exponential time complexity.